# How to get minimum and maximum values of columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to make a conceptual check of my code. The goal is to calculate minimum value of the field `minTimestamp` and maximum value of the field `maxTimestamp` in the DataFrame `df`, and delete all other values.
For example:

df

```
src    dst  minTimestamp   maxTimestamp
1      3    1530809948     1530969948
1      3    1540711155     1530809945
1      3    1520005712     1530809940
2      3    1520005712     1530809940
```

The answer should be the following one:

result:

```
src    dst  minTimestamp   maxTimestamp
1      3    1520005712     1530969948
2      3    1520005712     1530809940
```

This is my code:

```
val cw_min = Window.partitionBy($"src", $"dst").orderBy($"minTimestamp".asc)
val cw_max = Window.partitionBy($"src", $"dst").orderBy($"maxTimestamp".desc)

val result = df
  .withColumn("rn", row_number.over(cw_min)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn")
  .withColumn("rn", row_number.over(cw_max)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn")
```

Is it possible to use `Window` function sequentially as I did in my code sample?
The problem is that I always get the same values of `minTimestamp` and `maxTimestamp`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not do use spark SQL and do

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myDf")
val df2 = spark.sql("""
    select 
      src, 
      dst, 
      min(minTimestamp) as minTimestamp, 
      max(maxTimestamp) as maxTimestamp 
    from myDf group by src, dst""")
```

You can also use the API to do the same:

```
val df2 = df
   .groupBy("src", "dst")
   .agg(min("minTimestamp"), max("maxTimestamp"))
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete example?

Comment: I don't know why but I always forget the option of using Spark SQL:)

Comment: I also added a different way of doing it.

Comment: @botchniaque, why aggregating $"src" and $"dst" as well?  Also, I don't think your Spark SQL statement (without any grouping) is equivalent to your DataFrame API's.

Comment: @Leo C you're right, it's a mistake to repeat grouping columns in the `agg` function - the resulting `Dataframe` retains the grouping columns. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DataFrame `groupBy` to aggregate the `min` and `max`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 3, 1530809948L, 1530969948L),
  (1, 3, 1540711155L, 1530809945L),
  (1, 3, 1520005712L, 1530809940L),
  (2, 3, 1520005712L, 1530809940L)
).toDF("src", "dst", "minTimestamp", "maxTimestamp")

df.groupBy("src", "dst").agg(
    min($"minTimestamp").as("minTimestamp"), max($"maxTimestamp").as("maxTimestamp")
  ).
  show
// +---+---+------------+------------+                                             
// |src|dst|minTimestamp|maxTimestamp|
// +---+---+------------+------------+
// |  2|  3|  1520005712|  1530809940|
// |  1|  3|  1520005712|  1530969948|
// +---+---+------------+------------+
```